# How can I send keyboard input to USB port or Serial Port?

Tags: usb, rs232, keyboard

Now, I am using Windows 8 and have made Arduino buttons to operate as an keyboard's 4 arrow keys(up,down, right and left). From this moment, I am going to send this keyboard input event out to the USB port or 9-pin serial port(RS232) installed on the backside of a desktop.

I guess I may need to use windows header and serial communication but thoroughly have no idea, what program or language(C is preferred.) do I have to use. Also even a hardware connection.

Could I get a insight for my goal?

Comment: Can you draw a diagram of the setup you want? If the Arduino is generating the button signal, why don't you just get it to talk directly to whatever you plan to plug into the PC's USB port and avoid having to write any code on the PC.

Comment: As I am going to apply additional process in signal communication, I trying to send signal via PC. 

I may have to connect PC to MCU thru either RS232 port or USB. And that MCU would control a stepper motor finally. "The issue is how could I send the keyboard input to MCU thru USB or rs232. There have been many advice but they weren't showing detail method... even language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I basically see two options here:

- Use your Arduino to become a virtual keyboard (a HID device just like your regular keyboard). This will look to your PC like you have an additional keyboard connected - probably [this helps for a start](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/MouseKeyboard).
- Use the serial port on your Arduino to send out the data, then read it on your PC using some tool (this is basically your idea). It's pretty easy to do this using C#, it already provides a class called "SerialPort" which basically does the reading for you once you've set it up correctly. From here on, it depends what you want to do with the data you send. [An easy example can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053759/simplest-console-serialport-program-in-c-sharp).

Comment: Arduino as an HID? As my arduino is already working as a keyboard, I need a next step, which can process this keyboard input be sent out to the COM port like USB or rs232. Can it be done by C programming?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve .. do you want to press a button on the Arduino which shall then be transferred to the PC or the other way round. What it the ultimate goal you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes, sir. Please lemme give you a brief. Basically, it begins with 'Arduino Esplora' which includes joystick module on it. And I programmed this joystick work as an 'keyboard arrow keys' using Sketch-Arduino compiler.

Comment: and what's the goal you're trying to achieve in the end?

Comment: At this point I concluded that the control of arrow keys are up to Arduino. Next step is sending this keyboard event-which is happened from joystick movement-to external MCU which is connected to PC with USB or RS232 port. The MCU is controlling stepper motor and with a signal from PC, It would operate or stop the motor.

Comment: Here is a flow for understanding. 'Joystick up > keyboard arrow up pushed > Send this signal to MCU > MCU spins its motor' My issue is 'Sending signal to MCU'. People suggested diverse serial comm. programs and routes but no specific ideas. Your insight was already helpful and thankful but if there's a chance to get another comment from you, that'd be :-)

Comment: So basically your task is to generate these events ("push the joystick"), send it to a PC, the PC in turn sends it to another microcontroller which will then control some motors. The question arises: Why not control the motor from your Arduino directly? Can you use the motor drivers on the other board from your Arduino? If not and you really want to go the way through the PC, you can build a simple C or C# program which receives characters from one RS232 interface and sends it out the other. For a start, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036716/serial-comm-using-writefile-readfile